# How to select a row having a column with min value

Tags: oracle, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am using oracle database and spring ibatis.

I have a query which will return two results from that i need to get a record which has minimum value on a column.

In Oracle i do that using below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ANUMBER$ROOT ROOT 
WHERE ROOT.ROOT_NUMBER=1546305 
AND ROOT.MOL_WEIGHT = (SELECT MIN(MOL_WEIGHT) 
                       FROM ANUMBER$ROOT 
                       WHERE ROOT_NUMBER=1546305);
```

I have converted this query to like below in spring ibatis

```
SELECT * 
FROM ANUMBER$ROOT ROOT 
WHEREe ROOT.ROOT_NUMBER= #value# 
AND ROOT.MOL_WEIGHT = (SELECT MIN(MOL_WEIGHT) 
                       FROM ANUMBER$ROOT 
                       WHERE ROOT_NUMBER= #value#);
```

But this throws me below error:

> **log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in
>   thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
>   SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL
>   state [null]; error code [0];
>   --- The error occurred in abbott/gprd/compoundInfo/dao/ibatis/LibraCompoundInformationLookup.xml.
>
> --- The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for execution.
>   --- Check the selectCompoundInfoByRootNumber.
>   --- Check the SQL statement.
>   --- Cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>   --- The error occurred in abbott/gprd/compoundInfo/dao/ibatis/LibraCompoundInformationLookup.xml.
>
> --- The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for execution.
>   --- Check the selectCompoundInfoByRootNumber.
>   --- Check the SQL statement.
>   --- Cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>   --- The error occurred in abbott/gprd/compoundInfo/dao/ibatis/LibraCompoundInformationLookup.xml.
>
> --- The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for execution.
>   --- Check the selectCompoundInfoByRootNumber.
>   --- Check the SQL statement.
>   --- Cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException   at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:188)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForObject(GeneralStatement.java:104)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:566)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$1.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:241)
>     at
>   abbott.gprd.compoundInfo.dao.ibatis.CompoundInformationDao.getCompoundInformationForRootNumber(CompoundInformationDao.java:66)
>     at
>   abbott.gprd.compoundInfo.dao.ibatis.CompoundInformationDao.main(CompoundInformationDao.java:183)
>   Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.sql.simple.SimpleDynamicSql.processDynamicElements(SimpleDynamicSql.java:90)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.sql.simple.SimpleDynamicSql.getSql(SimpleDynamicSql.java:45)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:168)
>     ... 9 more ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment,
>   jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2 JDWP exit error
>   AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]**

Can anyone please help me in converting this query from oracle to spring ibatis?

Comment: I would change #value# for 1546305 and try if it works.

Comment: That doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

You can find the row(s) with the minimum value for a given column using the `RANK` (or `DENSE_RANK`) analytic function (and this does not need the extra correlated query):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT root.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY MOL_WEIGHT ) AS rnk
  FROM   ANUMBER$ROOT ROOT 
  WHERE  ROOT_NUMBER=1546305
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But the problem the table name contain another $ when used in java like **ANUMBER$$ROOT**